# KDE disable sounds of desktops not being viewed

Tags: audio, kde

I am using Manjaro KDE desktop. I have 4 different desktop environments. I want to be able to stream a different video to each one and be able to flip through them at will. I have successfully done everything up to this point. The only problem I have is that the sound from all the streams play at ounce. I have searched unsuccessfully for a way to fix the audio so only the desktop I am viewing is played.

Does anyone know if/how this can be accomplished?